# showing divs after content loaded

Tags: html

I have 4 divs (div1, div2, div3, div4) that I want to show individually after the content of each one has loaded.

For instance, after content of div1 has loaded, div1 is showed ... after content of div2 has loaded, div2 is showed ... and so on.

I know how to make the content of the entire page shows after all content is loaded, but I can't find a way to do this without writing the same code for each one of the divs, and I'd like to know an optimized way to do it.

Also I'd like to show a image in each one of the divs while the content is being loaded.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you use Jquery? What about use $(document).ready(function () { //show divs });

Comment: but I've got to make a "ready function" to each one of the divs?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the thing you're searching for is [jQuery queue](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/)

Answer (score 0):

In your main document you could just hide the DIV like this:

```
<div id="classname" style="overflow:hidden; display:none;">
```

And then at the end of your code which loads your content (assuming your doing something like a sql data load) just call a function to show the DIV like this:

```
ShowHide('classname');
```

The function would look something like this:

```
function ShowHide(h) {
    var tbl = document.getElementById(h);
    tbl.style.display == 'block' ? tbl.style.display = 'none' : tbl.style.display = 'block';
}
```

For showing a loading image in the mean time maybe create another DIV that is hidden at the same time your main DIV is shown.  I'm sure there i